# Can't start Eclipse Juno (Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: 12.10, eclipse

I installed eclipse though the ubuntu software center but I experienced some issues and I wanted to install the official eclipse version.

I downloaded eclipse classic 4.2.1 from [here:](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.1-201209141800/eclipse-SDK-4.2.1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)

Extracted it, but if I double click "eclipse" it doesn't do anything.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

my eclipse.ini looks like this

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar 
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-showsplash
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

I also deinstalled openJDK and installed jdk7.

Comment: The best way to debug the problem is open a terminal, change the directory to where you have eclipse and run it in terminal, using `./eclipse`. The output should help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Okay it seems that I have installed ubuntu 32 bit. Doesn't make any sense , the iso that I have hear is named AMD64 but the terminal doesn't lie `file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object` I just redownload ubuntu and reinstall it and try again. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the jvm in eclipse.ini file.

```
-vm
/path/to/jdk/bin/java
```

Comment: I added the path to the vm in the ini (updated my first post). But it still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines. According to http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: Also The -vm option must occur before the -vmargs option, since everything after -vmargs is passed directly to the JVM

Comment: I updated my .ini file and it still doesnt work. Maybe it is corrupted. I'll try a different version.

Comment: I have added this and also check it as executable

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

- Have you changed ownership of the Eclipse directory to your
  user/group, and did you check file rights? They might be still set to root.
- Do you have an Ubuntu 64bit system running?
- Did you install Java (JVM / JDK) - if so, does it conflict with the version requirements?

Some more hints can be found [here](https://ksearch.wordpress.com/2012/10/26/how-do-i-install-eclipse-juno-in-ubuntu-12-04/) and in the [Eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Install_a_JVM)

Comment: I just extracted the files in my download folder. I have Ubuntu 64bit and Eclipse 4.2.1 64bit. I deinstalled openJDK now and installed JDK7. I still can't run it. Just nothing happens:(

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse 4.2.1 seems to be incompatible with version `1.10` of `libwebkitgtk-1.0.0`

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392967

In order to install Eclipse 4.2.1 in Ubuntu 12.10 (64 bits) you need to downgrade `libwebkit` to `1.8.3`.

1. Download the files described in

   https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392967#c8
2. Install them by doing

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_1.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb libwebkitgtk-1.0-common_1.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_1.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Then run

   ```
   eclipse -clean
   ```

This worked very well in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Eclipse through direct download as well as Software Centre but on ubuntu 12.04 LTS they both seem to hang on splash screen unless the ~/workspace directory is deleted.

I found that by clicking on the splash screen and then pressing Enter it launches perfectly fine even without removing the ~/workspace directory!!